# Intent extras is not updating

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

I am trying to get string from browser. I used SEND action in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

In MainActivity.java, I have following code

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent receivedIntent=getIntent();
    etSearch.setText(getStringFromIntent(receivedIntent));
}

public String getStringFromIntent(Intent receivedIntent) {
    // get the action
    String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();
    // find out what we are dealing with
    String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();
    if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
        if (receivedType.startsWith("text/")) {
            // get the received text
            String receivedText = receivedIntent
                    .getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            // check we have a string
            if (receivedText != null) {
                // set the text
                return receivedText.trim();
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

For the first time I try to SHARE everything is working correctly
[image]

When I am trying to do that again text is not updating
[image]

I thought that it is because of onCreate(). So I moved code into onResume(). Nothing happened.

According to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19530081/2255924) I have added `receivedIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` and

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

No effect.

What should I do in order to update intent extra?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT when creating your PendingIntent to update the extras from a new Intent.

[Intent extras not removed/replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324471/intent-extras-not-removed-replaced)

or

PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT

```
private void send(Intent intentShowApp) {
    PendingIntent showAppPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentShowApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    try {
        showAppPendingIntent.send();
    } catch (CanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`